# React class component unusual this binding on methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, es6-class

For an example class component like below:

```
class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    list: ["First Todo"],
    text: ""
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this && this.setState) {
      console.log("this present in handleSubmit");
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        list: prevState.list.concat(this.state.text),
        text: ""
      }));
    } else {
      console.log("this not present in handleSubmit");
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    if (this && this.setState) {
      console.log("this present in handleChange");
      this.setState({
        text: e.target.value
      });
    } else {
      console.log("this not present in handleChange");
    }
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    if (!this || !this.setState) {
      console.log("this not present in removeItem");
    }
    console.log("this present in removeItem");
    const list = this.state.list;
    list.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ list });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
          <button>Add</button>
          <ol>
            {this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  {item}
                  <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(index)}>Delete</button>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ol>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The behavior of `this` binding to the class methods is not consistent.

Playing around with the component we will find that, `handleChange` and `removeItem` has the correct `this` context, whereas `handleSubmit` has `this` context as `undefined`.

Both of the function which has correct `this` context is represented as an arrow function in jsx. Like below:

```
<input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
```

While the `handleSubmit` is passed as function itself. Like below:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

But, I really don't know why this is happening. Because, In my understanding, it should not have mattered how the function was passed i.e. as the function itself or arrow representation as above.

[image: Edit React example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions have lexical `this`. Which means [its value is determined by the surrounding scope](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html). So when you use it instead of `class methods` the `this` value will be maped to the instance. But when you call `this.onSubmit` `this` will be refering to the local scope and not to the instance itself. To solve it either use `arrow functions` or `bind` the `onSubmit` method in your constructor.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes. That makes sense. I actually use `arrow function` most of the time.

Comment: I always use arrow functions but it's definitely not a rule.

Comment: Yes, `binding` saves memory footprint per instance, so, there may be use case when we use a lot of instance of some component.

Comment: I am still confused in one thing. The arrow function uses surrounding this. So, inside arrow function in render method, this refers to class's this. But, when you call class method from that arrow function, how the context is set to that class method. It would have made sense if we used this.handleChange.call(this, e).

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, it should not have mattered how the function was passed...

So here is new thing to learn

Passing `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}` will be the same as using `.bind` in the constructor or passing the reference and using `.bind`.

When passing it as an arrow function in the render method, it will get the `this` of the component instead of the method's this.

You should notice that `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}` is not a good practice because on every render you will be creating a new function.

Comment: `You should notice that onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}` 
Yes, good catch, it was created only for the purpose of this example.